# How to convert a string of a list into a list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a text file filled with lines like this:

```
[[19.305199999999999, -126.56959999999999], [19.445499999999999, -126.46599999999999], [19.196999999999999, -126.396], [19.130700000000001, -126.65900000000001], [19.378900000000002, -126.73]]
```

When I read these lines, they are interpreted as strings.  Is there any way I can read them as lists or arrays or easily convert them into lists or arrays?

Comment: you want them in a single list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ast` module

**Ex:**

```
import ast
l = "[[19.305199999999999, -126.56959999999999], [19.445499999999999, -126.46599999999999], [19.196999999999999, -126.396], [19.130700000000001, -126.65900000000001], [19.378900000000002, -126.73]]"
print(ast.literal_eval(l))
```

**Output:**

```
[[19.3052, -126.5696], [19.4455, -126.466], [19.197, -126.396], [19.1307, -126.659], [19.3789, -126.73]]
```